# Infer extended type from class given as property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My question is essentially what type do I have to change my `queries` type to so that this will compile for any given model class inputs? For this example there is an `AModel` with an `aProperty` and a `BModel` with a `bProperty` but I would like this to work for any class (given as the `model` property in the `Query` object) that extends `BaseModel`.

```
class BaseModel {
    baseProperty: any;
}

class AModel extends BaseModel {
    aProperty: any;
}

class BModel extends BaseModel {
    bProperty: any;
}

type Query<T extends typeof BaseModel> = {
    model: T,
    filter: Partial<InstanceType<T>>;
}

const queries: Query<typeof BaseModel>[] = [{
    model: AModel,
    filter: {aProperty: 0}
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'aProperty' does not exist in type 'Partial<BaseModel>'
}
{
    model: BModel,
    filter: {bProperty: false}
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bProperty' does not exist in type 'Partial<BaseModel>'
}];
```

Should note that this code works fine:

```
const queries: Query<typeof BaseModel>[] = [{
    model: AModel,
    filter: {aProperty: 0}
} as Query<typeof AModel>,
{
    model: BModel,
    filter: {bProperty: false}
} as Query<typeof BModel>]
```

but don't think I should need the rather lengthy casts for the actual use-case I have for this. Should also note that both `typeof AModel` and `typeof BModel` do extend `typeof BaseModel`. Even if a union type was viable in the context of this use-case, `Query<typeof AModel | typeof BModel>` does not work either. An insight is that `(Query<typeof AModel> | Query<typeof BModel>)[]` is the inferred type for `queries` so perhaps there exists some `infer` call that would find this type for any given `Query` objects but this is not something I am versed in.

Comment: "Even if a union type was viable in the context of this use-case" means that it isn't viable?  Because if it is, you can use [distributive conditional types](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to make it work like [this](//tsplay.dev/wX2nDm). ...

Comment: ...  You could use a generic helper function to *infer* a union, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLL9am). TypeScript lacks direct support for *existentially quantified generics* as proposed in [ms/TS#14466](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), so there's no simple specific type that means "an array of `Query<T>` elements for *some* unknown `T extends typeof BaseModel`".  There are ways to emulate such types in TS but they are probably more annoying than any other solution you were thinking of.

Comment: Let me know if you want any of that fleshed out into an answer.